# Wordpress clear template cache for Page Templates?

Tags: wordpress, caching, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, cache-control

I have a CPT custom post type of Books. The single template being used is 'single-books.php'. However, when I make changes to this file, they don't show up in the front-end. There is no browser or server caching.

I tested this by creating a new book post with the slug 'test'. Then, I duplicated the template and renamed it 'single-books-test.php'. As expected, the new book page started loading this template. However, when I made changes to 'single-books-test.php', the new changes won't show up.

Is there any way to clear Wordpress page template cache? Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your case but I’ve just discovered that the template I am using ([Nanospace](https://wordpress.org/themes/nanospace/)) itself utilizes a WordPress caching mechanism and the page is only re-rendered when I change the page using the WordPress editor.
The caching mechanism consists of two PHP functions: [`get_transient()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_transient/) and [`set_transient()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_transient/).

In the particular case of the Nanospace template, I found the `get_transient()` call in the file `wp-content/themes/nanospace/includes/frontend/class-post.php`:

```
$output    = get_transient( $cache_key );
if ( ! $output ) {
```

and changed it to following:

```
$output = false;
if ( ! $output ) {
```

My changes are now applied as I expected.